# How to fix this list-group in Bootstrap 4?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, bootstrap-4

I have 2 issues in this code that want to fix.

1) I want to move icons vertically center in li

2) I am not sure how to overcome the challenge connected with links. As you see I've added the whole li in the a tags. I want to let users navigate to  that chat when they click on it but at the same time I want to let   them mark the notification as read or remove it by clicking the right    icon in the same li I've added click events on both icons but not    sure if a tag of the whole li will let it work correctly.

Here is the code:

```css
section {
  background: #2193b0;
  /* fallback for old browsers */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to right, #6dd5ed, #2193b0);
  /* Chrome 10-25, Safari 5.1-6 */
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #6dd5ed, #2193b0);
  /* W3C, IE 10+/ Edge, Firefox 16+, Chrome 26+, Opera 12+, Safari 7+ */
  padding-top: 5%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
}

.emp-profile {
  border-radius: 0.5rem;
  background: #fff;
  padding: 5%
}

.profile-img {
  text-align: center;
}

.profile-img img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.material-icons {
  color: #2193b0 !important;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-left: 30px;
}

.list-group li {
  padding: 10px 50px
}

.list-group li p {
  color: #222222
}

.list-group li a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.toolbar-scroll {
  overflow-y: auto;
}

#toolbar-content {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row
}

.message {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

#list-group {
  flex: 1 1;
}

.chat {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.chat img {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #222222
}

.chat .username {
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #2193b0;
}

.chat .letter {
  margin-top: 0;
  padding-top: 0
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">


<section>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="emp-profile justify-content-center">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8">
          <ul class="list-group clearfix">
            <li class="list-group-item justify-content-center align-items-center mx-auto">
              <a class=" chat" href="#">

                <img src="http://emilcarlsson.se/assets/donnapaulsen.png" class="rounded-circle">
                <div class='message'>
                  <h3 class="d-xs-none username">Jessica</h3>
                  <p class="d-xs-none letter">StanIsLove aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa.</p>
                </div>
                <div class="float-right">
                  <i class="material-icons" (click)="MarkNotication(data)" [ngClass]="data.read ? 'disabled': 'notDisbled'">
                check
              </i>
                  <i class="material-icons" (click)="DeleteNotification(data)">
                delete_forever
              </i>
                </div>
              </a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

How can I fix these 2 issues? I am adding a full code link in the comment as well.

Comment: Here is the full code example: https://codepen.io/artyombaykov/pen/dQLeVM

Comment: `I want to move icons vertically center in li` not in `a`?

Comment: Yes as you see in the example it's on the top right now. while I need it on the right but vertically in the middle.

Comment: second point what you are trying to do exactly?

Comment: When the user clicks on a list item it navigates to the chat but at the same time he/she also can click on the mark or delete icon to either mark the notification as read or remove it from the list completely. I assume a tag is not set correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. use     `margin: auto;` to wrap div of icons [see here](https://codepen.io/leenmalka/pen/bQJjqp)

   (I added new class call `margin` and set in css `.margin{margin: auto;}`)
2. use [`event.stopPropagation();`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation) on click icon (use it after your code)

for example:

```
function MarkNotication(data,event){
   // your code to mark then:
   event.stopPropagation();
}
```

In html send the `event` to function:

```
  <i class="material-icons" (click)="MarkNotication(data,event)" [ngClass]="data.read ? 'disabled': 'notDisbled'">
    check
  </i>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Since I am using Angular and typescript functions are written in the other files. Will 2nd point look like this?

 <i class="material-icons" (click)="MarkNotication(data); event.stopPropagation()" [ngClass]="data.read ? 'disabled': 'notDisbled'">
            check
          </i>

Comment: no! send in html the event `(click)="MarkNotication(data,event);"`

Comment: Thank you so much I am marking the answered since the 1st point was perfect and I will check the second point in the evening to see it in action.

Answer (score 0):

1. You could easily center the icons vertically by adding:

   .material-icons {
     height: 100px;
     line-height: 100px;
   }

Make sure `height == line-height`.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the classes `d-flex` and `align-items-center` to the container of the icons in order to **center them vertically**:

```css
section {
  background: #2193b0;
  /* fallback for old browsers */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to right, #6dd5ed, #2193b0);
  /* Chrome 10-25, Safari 5.1-6 */
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #6dd5ed, #2193b0);
  /* W3C, IE 10+/ Edge, Firefox 16+, Chrome 26+, Opera 12+, Safari 7+ */
  padding-top: 5%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
}

.emp-profile {
  border-radius: 0.5rem;
  background: #fff;
  padding: 5%
}

.profile-img {
  text-align: center;
}

.profile-img img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.material-icons {
  color: #2193b0 !important;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-left: 30px;
}

.list-group li {
  padding: 10px 50px
}

.list-group li p {
  color: #222222
}

.list-group li a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.toolbar-scroll {
  overflow-y: auto;
}

#toolbar-content {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row
}

.message {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

#list-group {
  flex: 1 1;
}

.chat {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.chat img {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #222222
}

.chat .username {
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #2193b0;
}

.chat .letter {
  margin-top: 0;
  padding-top: 0
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/material-design-icons/3.0.1/iconfont/material-icons.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">


<section>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="emp-profile justify-content-center">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8">
          <ul class="list-group clearfix">
            <li class="list-group-item justify-content-center align-items-center mx-auto">
              <a class=" chat" href="#">

                <img src="http://emilcarlsson.se/assets/donnapaulsen.png" class="rounded-circle">
                <div class='message'>
                  <h3 class="d-xs-none username">Jessica</h3>
                  <p class="d-xs-none letter">StanIsLove aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa.</p>
                </div>
                <div class="float-right d-flex align-items-center">
                  <i class="material-icons" (click)="MarkNotication(data)" [ngClass]="data.read ? 'disabled': 'notDisbled'">
                check
              </i>
                  <i class="material-icons" (click)="DeleteNotification(data)">
                delete_forever
              </i>
                </div>
              </a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```